# Is there a way to add a label to draggable and droppable items in react-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using react-beautiful-dnd to create draggable bars of text that I want to move from a right card to a left card. I want the draggable bars of text to appear under a label but the labels all get put together in a couple of lines.

E.g. if i have three labels, "label 1", "label 2", "label 3" all the labels will get put together and they will appear as "label 1label 2label 3" but I want it to look like

"label 1

[       draggable bar of text             ]

label 2

[       draggable bar of text             ]

label 3

[       draggable bar of text             ]
"

I used Material-UI's InputLabel component for the label I want. The code looks like this:

```
<InputLabel
key={item + String(index)}
htmlFor={item}
>
{item}
</InputLabel>
```

I've tried wrapping the draggable in a div so I can give it a name and id.

```
<div name={item._type} id={item._type}>
<Draggable>
...
</Draggble>
<div>
```

Below is the entirety of the code

```
<GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
{this.state.configTypes.map((item, index) => (
<InputLabel
key={item + String(index)}
htmlFor={item}
>
{item}
</InputLabel>
))}
<Droppable droppableId="droppable">
{(provided, snapshot) => (
<div
ref={provided.innerRef}
style={dropdownListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
>
{this.state.configs.map((item, index) => (
<div name={item._type} id={item._type}>
<Draggable
key={item.name + String(index)}
draggableId={item.name + String(index)}
                              index={index}
>
{(provided, snapshot) => (
<div
ref={provided.innerRef}
{...provided.draggableProps}
{...provided.dragHandleProps}
style={dropdownItemStyle(
snapshot.isDragging,
provided.draggableProps.style
)}
>
{item.name}
</div>
)}
</Draggable></div>
))}
{provided.placeholder}
</div>
)}
</Droppable>
</GridItem>
```

Expected results:

"label 1

[       draggable bar of text             ]

label 2

[       draggable bar of text             ]

label 3

[       draggable bar of text             ]
"

Actual results:

"label 1label 2label 3

[       draggable bar of text             ]

[       draggable bar of text             ]

[       draggable bar of text             ]
"

Answer (score 0):

`react-beatiful-dnd` requires that the `Draggable`'s be visual siblings, which is not the case with your implementation, [see here](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/draggable.md#draggable-s-should-be-visible-siblings).

If you want to merely group the `Draggable`'s like [this](https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.com/?path=/story/complex-vertical-list--grouped) have a look at [this example story](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/stories/src/vertical-grouped/quote-app.jsx).

Otherwise you just have to add another child to the `Draggable` child function to which you apply the provided `draggableProps` and `dragHandleProps`

```
{(provided, snapshot) => (
    <div>
        <InputLabel
                key={item + String(index)}
                htmlFor={item}>
                {item}
        </InputLabel>
        <div ref={provided.innerRef}
            {...provided.draggableProps}
            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
            style={dropdownItemStyle(
                snapshot.isDragging,
                provided.draggableProps.style
            )}
            >
            {item.name}
        </div>
    </div>
)}
```